# Python subprocess command execution got stuck

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess, gnu-coreutils

I have an issue where a unix command executed with the python subprocess module is stuck:
(The full code is here:
 https://github.com/discoproject/disco/blob/master/lib/disco/worker/classic/func.py)

The unix command is a simple in-place sort.
The way the process is created:

> ```
> env = os.environ.copy()
> env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
> cmd, shell = sort_cmd(filename, sort_buffer_size)
> subprocess.check_call(cmd, env=env, shell=shell)
> ```

where the sort_cmd is:

> ```
> def sort_cmd(filename, sort_buffer_size):
>     return (r"sort -z -t$'\xff' -k 1,1 -T . -S {0} -o {1} {1}"
>         .format(sort_buffer_size, filename), True)
> ```

The input file (which is also the output file) of the sort command is empty. The file was not empty before calling this command (it is printed).

The question is, if this is a python issue, how could the file be empty. (One hypothesis is this python 2.7 bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue19809).

Issuing strace on the sort process showed that it was stuck on a futex. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce this problem and I do not have the input file. When the sort process was killed manually, it returned (with an error of course).

I am using gnu coreutils 8.10

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be a python issue, as it all happens from within the subshell and Python has no notion that it is a filename whatsoever.

In fact, the `sort` command outputs its output file for writing and empties it. If it is the input file at the same time, you are lost.

A solution could be to output everything into a temporary file and rename that afterwards.

Comment: Using a temp file is not the best solution because we have to be conservative about disk usage.  The sort command is guaranteed to read everything and then start writing to the file.  It might be an issue with gnu sort, but I do not have enough evidence to rule out python bugs. Also, given that the sort is not issued in parallel mode, I do not get what kind of lock it needs.

Comment: @ShayanPooya Maybe it starts writing late, but obviously, the file is emptied quite early. All Python does is issue a system command. As said, it ha no notion about accessing a file. So how should it?